# ActiveModel Serializer sending all records instead of specified limited amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
class MetricsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    org = current_user.organization
    metrics = Metric.where(organization: org).last(100)
    render json: metrics, status: 200, include: [:organization]
  end
end
```

metrics model:

```
class Metric < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

organization:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :metrics
end
```

MetricSerializer:

```
class MetricSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids
  attributes :id, :provisioned_users, :connected_users, :created_at

  has_one :organization

end
```

OrganizationSerializer:

```
class OrganizationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :org_id, :gauth_enabled

  has_many :metrics
end
```

the JSON though that gets returned

```
organizations: [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "ACME",
    org_id: "org_id232323",
    gauth_enabled: "f",
    metric_ids: [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      ...
      1000
    ]
  }
],
```

As you can see my serializer is spitting out every record in the Metric's table when I presumably only want the last 100.  I'm unsure what I've set up wrong in AMS (0.8).

Interestingly my rails console shows the right SQL with the correct limits:

```
Metric Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "metrics".* FROM "metrics"   ORDER BY "metrics"."id" DESC LIMIT 100
  Organization Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Comment: I'm confused; it looks like the JSON output might be coming from an `OrganizationsController` rather than the `MetricsController`. At least, the root element is `organizations`, not `metrics`. Can you post an example of the request, that's giving you the specified output?\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the guides on [associations](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable#associations):

> By default, serializers simply look up the association on the original object. You can customize this behavior by implementing a method with the name of the association and returning a different Array.

So, each model gets serialized according to its serializer. Your `organization` models were being put through your `OrganizationSerializer`, which had `has_many :metrics` specified. Thus, rails looked up all of the metrics for that organization, and serialized them.

You didn't want that, you just cared about the one organization which the metric belonged to. So simply remove that line, and rails won't serialize the rest.

Comment: thanks Sam - I do have an `OrganizationSerializer` and updated my question to include it.  That said, I still am having the issue.

Comment: only render json: metrics.to_json, status: 200
should do the trick!
oh you declared has many associations on the model but defined has_on association in serialization.